# NHibernate works under NUnit and Console but not under IIS [throws PropertyAccessException]

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an API which contains an object which looks like the following:

```
public class NOrgUnit {
    public virtual NOrgUnit Parent { get; set;}
    public virtual ISet<NOrgUnit> children { get; set; } // an Iesi 1.0.1 ISet
    public virtual Int64 Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    // etc.
}
```

The object has the following map:

```
public class NOrgUnitMap : ClassMap<NOrgUnit>
{
    public NOrgUnitMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        Map(x => x.Name);

        References(x => x.Parent).Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.children).AsSet();
    }
}
```

**When I build my API and reference it in a console application, everything works perfectly.**

When I reference the same .dll in an asp.net context (a sitecore project specifically), I receive an NHibernate exception:

```
Org Service encountered unexpected exception [NHibernate.PropertyAccessException: Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches); setter of TI.Organization.Core.Impl.DAL.Persistence.Entities.Hierarchy.NOrgUnit ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'TI.Security.Core.Impl.Management.Provisioning.DAL.PersistentGenericSet`1[TI.Organization.Core.Impl.DAL.Persistence.Entities.Hierarchy.NOrgUnit]' to type 'Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet`1[TI.Organization.Core.Impl.DAL.Persistence.Entities.Hierarchy.NOrgUnit]'.
   at (Object , Object[] , SetterCallback )
   at NHibernate.Bytecode.Lightweight.AccessOptimizer.SetPropertyValues(Object target, Object[] values)
   at NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.PocoEntityTuplizer.SetPropertyValuesWithOptimizer(Object entity, Object[] values)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.PocoEntityTuplizer.SetPropertyValuesWithOptimizer(Object entity, Object[] values)
   at NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.PocoEntityTuplizer.SetPropertyValues(Object entity, Object[] values)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.SetPropertyValues(Object obj, Object[] values, EntityMode entityMode)
   at NHibernate.Engine.TwoPhaseLoad.InitializeEntity(Object entity, Boolean readOnly, ISessionImplementor session, PreLoadEvent preLoadEvent, PostLoadEvent postLoadEvent)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.InitializeEntitiesAndCollections(IList hydratedObjects, Object resultSetId, ISessionImplementor session, Boolean readOnly)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
```

This has been stumping me for a few days now. Why would the application work in a console and not in IIS?

Comment: how are you configuring your Nhibernate in your console vs your IIS?

Comment: "IIS" is a pretty broad definition, do you mean the built-in IIS server in VS, or a "real" IIS, and if so, what's the version?

Comment: I'm running it under IIS 7.5.  I'm not configuring anything differently.

Answer (score 3):

`TI.Security.Core.Impl.Management.Provisioning.DAL.PersistentGenericSet<T>` is a strange class. Is this custom developed? If so, it probably doesn't implement `Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<T>`. If it does implement it, it may be a problem of having several Iesi assemblies loaded.

I never heard of sitecore, so maybe that is doing some strange things in the background.

Comment: That's from another assembly that also uses Nhibernate. I didn't notice that in the error message- you may be onto something, I'll get back to you.